# Little part of the string to integer parser vs Clean Code

Tags: java, strings, parsing

I started reading a *Clean Code* book and some other articles on the Internet about OOD and design patterns and I'm a little confused. I've started to code a little string to integer parser which currently parses a first integer in string larger than 0 or returns -1.

Could you look and give me some idea if this is written correctly with general rules of good programming? I'm not sure about usage of `Index` instances in the `IntegerSubstringer` class.

**`main` method**

```
public static void main (String Args[])
    {
        IntegerParser parser = new IntegerParser();
        System.out.println( parser.getFirstInt("Blaola") );
    }
```

**IntegerParser.java**

```
package stringParser.integerParser;

public class IntegerParser
{
    IntegerSubstringer substringer;

    public IntegerParser()
    {
        substringer = new IntegerSubstringer();
    }

    public int getFirstPositiveInt(String textToParse)
    {
        String numberSubstring = substringer.cutFirstNumber(textToParse);
        if(!numberSubstring.equals(""))
            return parse(numberSubstring);
        return -1;
    }

    private int parse(String substringContainingNumbersOnly)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(substringContainingNumbersOnly);
    }
}
```

**IntegerSubstringer.java**

```
package stringParser.integerParser;

public class IntegerSubstringer
{
    IntegerFinder finder;
    String text;
    Index startIndex;
    Index endIndex;

    public IntegerSubstringer()
    {
        finder = new IntegerFinder();
    }

    public String cutFirstNumber( String text )
    {
        this.text = text;
        setStartIndexAtTheFirstNumber();
        iterateToTheEndOfTheNumberSeries();
        if (startIndex.isInvalid()) return new String();
        return makeSubstringAccordToIndexes();
    }

    private void iterateToTheEndOfTheNumberSeries()
    {
        setEndIndexAfterStartIndex();
        while( endOfTextNotReached() && finder.letterIsANumber(text, endIndex) )
        {
            endIndex.increaseValue();
        }
        if (endIndex.isInvalid())
            setEndIndexAfterStartIndex();
    }

    private String makeSubstringAccordToIndexes()
    {
        return text.substring(startIndex.getValue(), endIndex.getValue());
    }

    private void setStartIndexAtTheFirstNumber()
    {
        startIndex = finder.findFirstNumber(text);
    }

    private void setEndIndexAfterStartIndex()
    {
        endIndex = new Index(startIndex);
        endIndex.increaseValue();
    }

    private boolean endOfTextNotReached()
    {
        return text.length() > endIndex.getValue();
    }
}
```

**IntegerFinder.java**

```
package stringParser.integerParser;

import stringParser.LetterTypeArbiter;

public class IntegerFinder
{
    private LetterTypeArbiter rater;
    private Index index;

    public IntegerFinder()
    {
        index = new Index();
        rater = new LetterTypeArbiter();
    }

    public Index findFirstNumber ( String text )
    {
        for ( index.resetValue(); index.getValue() < text.length() ; index.increaseValue() )
            if ( stringHasANumberAtIndex(text, index) )
                return index;
        return new InvalidIndex();
    }

    public boolean letterIsANumber ( String text, Index currentIndex )
    {
        index = new Index(currentIndex);

        if ( stringHasANumberAtIndex(text, index) )
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean stringHasANumberAtIndex ( String text, Index index )
    {
        return rater.obtainsANumber( getLetterFromString(text, index) );
    }

    private int getLetterFromString ( String text, Index index )
    {
        return text.charAt( index.getValue() );
    }
}
```

**Index.java**

```
package stringParser.integerParser;

public class Index
{
    private int value;

    public Index()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public Index( Index index )
    {
        value = index.getValue();
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void resetValue()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public void increaseValue()
    {
        value++;
    }

    public boolean isInvalid()
    {
        return value < 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So given an input `abc123`, it should return `123`? This is really quite a complicated solution if that's the case...

Comment: Like many mentioned before me, this seems like an over design. Finding an int in a string can be done in 5-10 lines. You don't need 5 classes for that. Another note, your class and function names are too long. You should try to be more consise. For example makeSubstringAccordToIndexes would be more readable in a form of Substring(start, length) or substringContainingNumbersOnly could be numericString

Comment: This is only one possible functionality of the parser. I wanted to stay open for new functionalities ( like remove first number after specific substring ) in the future.

Answer (score 4):

### Index = int

My first thought as I skimmed through your code was that you have a whole class that seems to be nothing more than a wrapper for an int.  The only method of any significance is `isInvalid()` which could easily be moved to somewhere else or just inlined when needed.  I think it would be best to remove this class and just use ints as indices.

### KISS

I didn't read the rest of the code very thoroughly but it seems like a lot of code to solve a simple problem.  I prefer the KISS methodology (keep it simple stupid) to complicated solutions.  I'm sure if you tried to rewrite your code with simplicity as a goal, you could come up with something much smaller and simpler.

Here's an example of how you could simplify.  You have this function:

```
private int parse(String substringContainingNumbersOnly)
{
    return Integer.parseInt(substringContainingNumbersOnly);
}
```

Notice that all it does is call another function.  You could remove this function and replace the call to it with the call to `Integer.parseInt` directly.  Now someone reading the code will know exactly what your code is doing when they read that line.  With your current code, they would have to skip to the definition of `parse` to figure out what is happening, because the function name "parse" doesn't really explain what it does.

In fact many of your functions are one liners.  Instead of having these one line functions which are mostly called from one place only, you could just put the one line in the calling function and add a comment about what is happening (if it isn't clear already).  Right now, it almost seems like every line of code is a function call to a new function.

Comment: Ok. So I have few questions to you :) I've read that every primitive type needs to be wrapped. Why then we want to leave a primitive int hanging around? Moreover as I mentioned this isnt the whole parser. I would like to add more functionalities soon. How then should I start thinking about needed classes. Could you pls write a simple basic plan of this kind of parser? People write that it isnt the problem for few classes and I agree. I just wanted to make it open for new functions.

Comment: @hejcz Who told you to wrap primitive types?  That's crazy.  If you really need to have an object for a primitive type, use the java provided objects Integer, Long, etc.  I don't know what classes you will need without knowing what your parser needs to do.  But I would argue to always simplify when possible.  Having many classes is not something to be proud of.

Comment: So maybe i misunderstood something with primitives wrapping. Maybe that was something like instead of having int x,y we should have a Point object with x,y inside. However you say that this is bad to have many classes. Is this true according to Single Responsibility Principle? If class has one responsibility then how could it be big?

Comment: @hejcz It isn't necessarily bad to have a lot of classes.  But creating classes for no good reason is bad.  In your code above, I would have created 1 class only.  Later if I added more functionality, I would create more classes and maybe some of the code would move from one class to another.  It's hard to determine what classes you will need until you actually try to solve the problem.  Other people may have different ways of planning out their program, but I think a lot of time can be wasted making plans that will later change once you start finding out what all the problems really are.

Comment: @hejcz Btw you should know that I'm a C programmer.  So you might want to ask other people for their opinions also.  Things will get easier with more experience.  After you've written tens of thousands of lines of code, you will  start to understand how to divide your program into classes.

Comment: isn't C rather not OO language? :) Do you mean pure C or C++, C# as well? Even if I don't understand everything clearly, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: @hejcz That's right, my main language is not OO (pure C).  So I normally don't even use classes.  That is why you should get other opinions.

Comment: @hejcz From what I could see, the classes seem to be in a chain. The `Main` class has a reference to the `IntegerParser`, which has a reference to the `IntegerSubstringer`, which has a reference to the `IntegerFinder, etc. I wouldn't create that string of classes and would rather do it in one, or maximum two, classes.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on IntegerFinder:

- `findFirstNumber` is returning the object referenced by the field `index` which is mutable and will be changed by later calls to `IntegerFinder`'s methods. This can lead to serious and difficult-to-debug problems and will usually be [reported by automated bug-finding programs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EI_EXPOSE_REP). Return a copy of the index instead.
- The `index` field looks like it is reset every call to `findFirstNumber`. It is also set but the value is never used in `letterIsANumber`. Why is not not a local instance in `findFirstNumber`?
- `letterIsANumber` could just be written as `return stringHasANumberAtIndex(text, currentIndex)`
- `letterIsANumber` could probably be replaced with `Character.isDigit(String.codePointAt(index.getValue()))`

More generally

- Some of your classes look like procedures that have been split up into methods and single-use fields. I appreciate that you are experimenting with object-oriented thinking and may have future use in mind for IntegerSubstringer and IntegerFinder, but:
- Consider passing the `text` as a constructor argument to IntegerSearch if it is your intent for those objects to represent a state of parsing a string. Otherwise, move the  fields into locals to indicate that you don't intend to track the state across (public) method calls.
- If you haven't already, write some JUnit tests for your class. It will help you ensure the code is correct and may help you come up with better interfaces to your classes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want a simple program which for say input `abc123` returns `123`, so it extracts all `integers` from a `String`.

While your solution works, it really seems an over complication for such a simple task. You can do the same thing using `regex` in just a few lines

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    final String input = "ab123cxyz12xba2a4aaxy1";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); //will look for numbers in the String; matches digits; same as [0-9]
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        buffer.append(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}
```

You can read and learn more about regex [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples)